# How to replace a String in java which contains dot?

Tags: java, string

I need to replace a String which contains white space and periods. I have tried with the following code:

```
String customerName = "Mr. Raj Kumar";

customerName = customerName.replaceAll(" ", "");
System.out.println("customerName"+customerName);

customerName = customerName.replaceAll(".", "");
System.out.println("customerName"+customerName);
```

but this results in:

> customerName Mr.RajKumar

And

> customerName

I am getting the correct customer name from the first SOP, but from second SOP I am not getting any value.

Comment: Escape the dot with a backslash: `\.`

Answer (score 37):

escape the dot, or else it will match any character. This escaping is necessary, because [replaceAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) treats the first paramter as a regular expression.

```
customerName = customerName.replaceAll("\\.", "");
```

You can do the whole thing with one statement:

```
customerName = customerName.replaceAll("[\\s.]", "");
```

Comment: To elaborate on this correct answer: `replaceAll()` is working with regular expressions, not string literals.

Answer (score 6):

use this in your code just for remove periods

```
customerName = customerName.replaceAll("[.]","");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use **str.replace(".", "")** and it will replace all occurences of dot, Remember there is only one difference betwwen replace and replaceAll which is, later uses regex as input string where as first one uses simple character sequence.